# FontMetrics - Cap Height with freetype2

Tags: fonts, freetype2

I'm trying to retrieve the cap height for a particular font using freetype2 but I can't find a way to go about it via the API.  Does anybody know if this is even possible and if so what the api call is.  If not, any other font libraries (java, c, python, etc) that I could use?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems to work for me:

```
int maxHeight = (face_->bbox.yMax >> 6) - (face_->bbox.yMin >> 6);
```